# why does python dictionary adds ok on for loop but doesn't on outside - python

Tags: python

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,2,3,4,1,6,5,7,6,5,2,3,4,6,2,3,6,7]
counter = {}
for i in numbers:
    counter = {i : numbers.count(i)}

for j in range(1, 7):
    print(counter.get(1))
```

For somewhat reason,
the dictionary works fine at first for loop.
counter dictionary looks like this

{1:2, 2:4 etc.}

But it doesn't work on second for loop.
the dictionary only contains last key at here

{7:2}

what is the problem?

Comment: `counter = {i : numbers.count(i)}` overwrites `counter`, so only the last one is there when the first `for` completes,

Comment: Should be `counter[i] = numbers.count(i)` instead of `counter = ` that overwrites your variable each time

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter may be worth looking into...

Comment: Please use the debugge of your Python IDE to verify if the program is doing what you expect it to do (it's not - you're overwriting counter again and again in the first loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 problems:

- you are overwriting the dictionnary when you want to add to it
- when you call the dictionnary you always use key 1, and not your variable `j`
- `range(1,7)` gives the numbers 1 to 6 when you need 1 to 7, so `range(1,8)`
  I have modified the output to make it clear, you are free to modify it to suit your needs.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,2,3,4,1,6,5,7,6,5,2,3,4,6,2,3,6,7]
counter = {}
for i in numbers:
    counter[i] = numbers.count(i)
for j in range(1, 8):
    print(j,' is present ',counter.get(j),' times.')
```

output

```
1  is present  2  times.
2  is present  4  times.
3  is present  4  times.
4  is present  3  times.
5  is present  2  times.
6  is present  4  times.
7  is present  2  times.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the counter on every iteration. Just save the output for each key like :-

```
for i in numbers:
    counter[i] = numbers.count(i)
```

And also for your second loop use j instead of 1

```
for j in range(1, 7):
    print(counter.get(j))
```